# Weak lensing: Can tangential shear be negative?

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-lensing, weak-lensing

I am studying the stacked tangential shear profiles of a field of ~30,000 galaxies, with the aim of plotting the tangential shear profiles as a function of distance from the centre of the field. We can thus think of the galaxy field as a Cartesian coordinate system with the centre of the field at the origin of the coordinates.

For each galaxy we have a weight, $w$, ellipticities $e_1$ and $e_2$, and angular position $\phi$ with respect to the horizontal (i.e. a position of $\phi=90^0$ would be on the positive y-axis, $180^0$ on the negative x-axis, and $270^0$ on the negative y-axis), as well as many other measurements.

The tangential ellipticity is given by $$\tilde{e_t} = -Re\Big[\tilde{e}e^{-2i\phi}\Big]=-Re\Big[(e_1+ie_2)(\cos{2\phi}-i\sin{2\phi})\Big]=-e_1\cos{2\phi} -e_2\sin{2\phi}.$$

Of course, given that $\phi\in[0,360)$ and some of $e_1$ and $e_2$ are less than zero, some of these tangential ellipticities will less than zero, $\tilde{e_t}<0.$

The tangential shear per bin (I split the field into statistical bins) is $$\gamma_t = \frac{\sum_{i\in\text{bin}} \tilde{e_{t,i}w_i}}{\sum_{i\in\text{bin}}w_i}.$$ Thus, we end up with negative tangential shears because of the negative tangential ellipticity.

**KEY QUESTIONS**

Is this allowed?

If so, how could I then do a logarithmic plot?

If not, how do I get around it? I have thought of maybe taking the magnitude of the sums as the tangential shear calculation.